# Partial string matching using patterns

Tags: r, regex

I need to write a query in R to match partial string in column names. I am looking for something similar to LIKE operator in SQL. For e.g, if I know beginning, middle or end part of the string I would write the query in format:

```
LIKE 'beginning%middle%'
```

in SQL and it would return matching strings. In `pmatch` or `grep` it seems I can only specify 'beginning' , 'end' and not the order. Is there any similar function in R that I am looking for?

For example, say I am looking in the vector:

```
y <- c("I am looking for a dog",
       "looking for a new dog", "a dog", "I am just looking")
```

Let's say I want to write a query which picks `"looking for a new dog"` and I know start of the string is `"looking"` and end of string is `"dog"`. If I do a `grep("dog",y)` it will return `1,2,3`. Is there any way I can specify beginning and end in `grep`?

Comment: Can you show some test cases where `grep` failed you?

Comment: For example lets say I want to look into the vector y<- c("I am looking for a dog", "looking for a new dog", "a dog", "I am just looking"). Lets say I want to write a query which picks "looking for a new dog" and I know start of the string is "looking" and end of string is "dog". If I do a grep("dog",y) it will return 1,2,3,4. Is there any way I can specify beginning and end in grep? Thanks

Comment: I would edit your original question to include that example. That is important information.

Comment: `grep("dog", y)` should return `1 2 3` from that vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `grep` function supports regular expressions and with regular expressions, you can match almost anything

```
y<- c("I am looking for a dog", "looking for a new dog", "a dog", "I am just looking")
grep("looking.*dog",y, value=T)
# [1] "I am looking for a dog" "looking for a new dog"
```

Here this pattern looks for `looking` then "maybe something" then `dog`. So that should do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

In regular expressions, `^` specifies the beginning of the string, `$` specifies the end, thus:

```
y<- c("I am looking for a dog", "looking for a new dog", "a dog", "I am just looking")
grep("^looking.*dog$", y)
[1] 2
```