# How to create a function that return the value of a certain column according to the values of others columns in a df?

Tags: r, function

I have a data frame

```
  df <- data.frame(Lastname = c("Crosby", "Bourque", "Messier","Crosby", "Bourque", "Messier"), 
                 Name = c("Sid", "Ray", "Mark","Sid", "Ray", "Mark"), 
                 Season = c("2005-06","1997-98","1994-95","2006-07","1998-99","1995-96"),
                 Goals = c(20, 30, 40,30,50,60),
                 Assists= c(30,50,60,40, 50, 50),
                 Points = c(50, 80,100,70,100,110))
```

Which look like this:

```
      Lastname    Name    Season Goals Assists  Points
    1  Crosby     Sid    2005-06    20      30     50
    2 Bourque     Ray    1997-98    30      50     80
    3 Messier    Mark    1994-95    40      60    100
    4  Crosby     Sid    2006-07    30      40     70
    5 Bourque     Ray    1998-99    50      50    100
    6 Messier    Mark    1995-96    60      50    110
```

I want to create a function where I can obtain the statistics that I decided
for a certain player and season. I have this :

```
 library(plyr)
     printstats = function(lastname, name, season, x) {
      if(sum((df$Lastname==lastname)+(df$Name==name))==0 ) stop("There is a spelling error in ", lastname, " and ", name,".")
      if(sum(df$Lastname==lastname)==0) stop("There is a spelling error in ", lastname,".")
      if(sum(df$Name==name)==0) stop("There is a spelling error in ", name,".")
      if(sum(df$Season==season)==0) stop(season," does not exist.")
      #if(isTRUE(df[df$Lastame=="lastname" & df$Name=="name" & df$Season=="season",])==FALSE) stop(name," ", lastname, " did not play in ", season,".")
      df.sub <- df %>%
        filter(Lastname == lastname, Name == name, Season == season) %>% 
        select(Lastname, Name, Season, one_of(x)) 
      paste(name, lastname, " did", df.sub[, x], x, "in", season)
    }
```

When I try it, everythings work:

```
printstats("Crosby", "Sid","2005-06","Points")
```

"Sid Crosby  did 50 Points in 2005-06"

But if I remove the # to include the last "if" in my function, it is not working.
I want to be able to paste a sentence when the player did not play in the season 
requested in the function such as if I ask:

```
 printstats("Crosby", "Sid","1998-99","Points")
```

I want the function to tell me that Sid Crosby did not play in 1998-99.

How can I do that ???

Comment: (1) "Assists" is spelled incorrectly with 3 's' in your function ("Asssists"). (2) The filter for Points in your function uses "nom", "saison" instead of "name", "season".

It's not clear to me how the function can be working for "Points" given these errors.

Comment: In addition, extra `)` in `select(Name, Surname, Season, Assists))` in both "Assists" and "Goals", the code does not run as is for `showstats("Crosby", "Sid","2005-06","Points")` unless you copied it incorrectly from your source code.

Comment: Why is `x =="Goals"`  part of your `filter` when there isn't a column named `x` that takes on a value like `"Goals"`?

Comment: Sorry, the variables name were not in english, thus I translated them. I did not see I made spelling errors while doing it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the advantages with R is to be able to access data frames by colnames or rownames, you should take advantage of this and your if statements are no longer necessary.

Here is a shorter code to illustrate.

I kept your designations but note that surname is usually understood to be the family name or last name. I may or may not have included/excluded someone.

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("Ovechkin", "Bourque", "Messier","Ovechkin", "Bourque", "Messier"), 
             Surname = c("Alex", "Ray", "Mark","Alex", "Ray", "Mark"), 
             Season = c("2005-06","1999-00","1994-95","2008-09","1992-93","1991-92"),
             Goals = c(52, 30, 40,56,50,60),
             Assists= c(54,50,60,54, 50, 50),
             Points = c(106, 80,100,110,100,110))

showstats = function(name, surname, season, x) {
    df %>%
    filter(Name == name, Surname == surname, Season == season) %>% 
    select(Name, Surname, Season, one_of(x))
} 
showstats("Ovechkin", "Alex","2008-09","Goals")
showstats("Ovechkin", "Alex","2008-09","Assists")
showstats("Ovechkin", "Alex","2008-09","Points")
```

Edited to answer additional question re: printing.  Note that x is assigned a character value that corresponds to one of the column names of interest. You can thus index the data frame with x.

```
printstats = function(name, surname, season, x) {
    df.sub <- df %>%
    filter(Name == name, Surname == surname, Season == season) %>% 
    select(Name, Surname, Season, one_of(x)) 
    paste(surname, name, "scored", df.sub[, x], x, "in", season)
}
printstats("Ovechkin", "Alex","2008-09","Goals")
```

Edited to include conditionals as requested and argument check:

```
printstats = function(lastname, name, season, statistic) {
  # check function arguments
  if (missing(lastname) | missing(name) | missing(season) | missing(statistic)) stop("Need to specify player lastname, name, season, statistic")

  # convert season xxxx-xxxx to xxxx-xx
  if (length(strsplit(season, split="")[[1]]) == 9) {
      season <- paste(c(strsplit(season, split="")[[1]][1:5], strsplit(season, split="")[[1]][8:9]), collapse="")
  }
  if(sum(df$Season==season)==0) {
    print(paste("The", season, "season is not included in this database."))
  } else {
    if (sum(df$Lastname == lastname) == 0) {
      print(paste0("Player of last name ", lastname, " is not in the database. Please check spelling of ", lastname))
    } else {
      if (sum(df$Lastname==lastname & df$Name==name) == 0) {
        print(paste0("Player of last name ", lastname, " found, but no entries for first name ", name, ". Available entries for ", lastname, " include:" ))
        print(unique(df[df$Lastname==lastname, c("Lastname", "Name")]))
      } else {
        if (sum(df$Lastname==lastname & df$Name==name & df$Season==season) == 0) {
          print(paste0(name, " ", lastname, " did not play in the ", season, ". Available seasons for this player include:" ))
          print(unique(df[df$Lastname==lastname & df$Name==name, c("Lastname", "Name", "Season")]))
        } else {
          df.sub <- df %>%
            dplyr::filter(Name == name, Lastname == lastname, Season == season) %>% 
            dplyr::select(Name, Lastname, Season, one_of(statistic)) 
          paste(df.sub[["Name"]], df.sub[["Lastname"]], "scored", df.sub[[statistic]], statistic, "in", df.sub[["Season"]])    
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
printstats("Sedin", "Henrik","2005-2006","Points")
printstats("Sedin", "Daniel","2005-2006","Points")
printstats("Crosby", "Sidney","2005-06","Points")
printstats("Crosbie", "Sidney","2005-06","Points")
printstats("Crosby", "Sid","2001-02","Points")
printstats("Bourque", "Ray", "2005-2006")
```

Here is a version insensitive to case:

```
printstats = function(lastname, name, season, statistic) {
  # check function arguments
  if (missing(lastname) | missing(name) | missing(season) | missing(statistic)) stop("Need to specify player lastname, name, season, statistic")

  # convert season xxxx-xxxx to xxxx-xx
  if (length(strsplit(season, split="")[[1]]) == 9) {
    season <- paste(c(strsplit(season, split="")[[1]][1:5], strsplit(season, split="")[[1]][8:9]), collapse="")
  }
  if(sum(df$Season==season)==0) {
    print(paste("The", season, "season is not included in this database."))
  } else {
    if (sum(tolower(df$Lastname) == tolower(lastname)) == 0) {
      print(paste0("Player of last name ", lastname, " is not in the database. Please check spelling of ", lastname))
    } else {
      if (sum(tolower(df$Lastname)==tolower(lastname) & tolower(df$Name)==tolower(name)) == 0) {
        print(paste0("Player of last name ", lastname, " found, but no entries for first name ", name, ". Available entries for ", lastname, " include:" ))
        print(unique(df[tolower(df$Lastname)==tolower(lastname), c("Lastname", "Name")]))
      } else {
        if (sum(tolower(df$Lastname)==tolower(lastname) & tolower(df$Name)==tolower(name) & df$Season==season) == 0) {
          print(paste0(name, " ", lastname, " did not play in the ", season, ". Available seasons for this player include:" ))
          print(unique(df[tolower(df$Lastname)==tolower(lastname) & tolower(df$Name)==tolower(name), c("Lastname", "Name", "Season")]))
        } else {
          df.sub <- df %>%
            dplyr::filter(tolower(Name) == tolower(name), tolower(Lastname) == tolower(lastname), Season == season) %>% 
            dplyr::select(Name, Lastname, Season, one_of(statistic)) 
          paste(df.sub[["Name"]], df.sub[["Lastname"]], "scored", df.sub[[statistic]], statistic, "in", df.sub[["Season"]])    
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
printstats("sedin", "Henrik","2005-2006","Points")
printstats("Sedin", "daniel","2005-2006","Points")
printstats("Crosby", "sidney","2005-06","Points")
printstats("CROSBY", "Sidney","2005-06","Points")
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working. I did not know the "one_of" function. It is way easier to obtain what I want.

Comment: If I want the answer to be print like this : Ovechkin scored 52 goals in 2005-06 
How can I do that ?

Comment: @Mark see edited code. Accept the answer when you are satisfied so this can be marked answered. see `?paste` or `?paste0`

Comment: How can I use the answer in the paste ? I am not able to write it as a code in comments but I have : print(paste0(name , " ", last name ," ", "scored ", x , " goals in " , season))                                             I do not know what to put instead of the x, to obtain the value found with my function...

Comment: Can you clarify? Did you see the edited answer above, there is now a new function `printstats` that prints what you wanted using paste. Are you asking how to return the output of `printstats` as a variable that you can use afterwards?

Comment: @ R.S.    I did not see it at first. Just to make sure I understand how it is working. You create an object "df.sub" which is  the row that is found with the function and then you are able to access the information in this row as in a data frame ?

Comment: Hi Mark, yes I assign the output that showstats was returning to the variable `df.sub` and use the colname character x to index it for the correct value.  All other paste elements are taken from the arguments fed to the the function.  For a fully functional function, you might consider printed output if the player or season stats are not available.  I also made the filter to a strict match `Surname == `surname`, so it will fail to return output if you use Sidney or Alexander rather than Sid or Alex.

Comment: On the other hand if you remove this condition, you can enter Henrik Sedin and stats for both Daniel and Henrik would appear as you only filer with Name, and that will also mess up your stats sentence.  You can consider perhaps partial Surname matching.

Comment: @ R.S. For your point of the fully functional function, in the best case scenario, I would like to print out different sentences according to the input. If Name is not found in the df, then print "There is a spelling error in the Name", same thing with the Surname, and for the season to print  (surname, name, "did not play", "in", season). Should I do it with if statement ? If so, they need to be at the beginning or the end of the function ?

Comment: The if statement should be in the beginning, so that if the player does not exist or did not play, it prints the warning message and exists, only when all conditions are met should it proceed to extract information.  Hierarchy should be last name, first name, then season.  If you want to be fancy you can consider partial string matching, where if someone looks for Sid Crosby the warning says: No player exists, do you mean Sidney Crosby?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901500/partial-string-matching-r.  Are you doing NHL stat analysis for fun?

Comment: By that I mean, how much robustness do you need from your code? If this is a more professional endeavor you should learn about checking arguments etc https://www.r-bloggers.com/programming-with-r-%E2%80%93-checking-function-arguments/, or simply look at the source code for the many functions in R to see how to set this up.

Comment: No, it is part for fun and part for school... I am learning R in school and I love hockey analytics, thus I combined the two ! I try to look at the source code in R, but it is not always easy to understand how it is working at first. I obtain almost what I wanted. I would like to incorporate partial string matching and find a way to be able to search when a player play is last and first season to be able to paste a sentence such as "(surname, name, " retired in " , ...) or "(surname, name, " start is career in " , ...) when the season written in the function doest match a season played

Comment: I have a problem finally with my function. Everything is alright except when I put a season the player did not play in . I am not able to create an if that look if there is a entry for the player for the season asked… 
For the spelling errors in the name I did : if(sum(df$Name==name)==0) stop("there is a spelling error in", name,".")
What “if “ I can do if I want to print stop(surname, name, “did not play in” , season) ?

Comment: @ R.S. How can I adjust the "if" that is not working ? Look, I re-edited the question.  Ty

Comment: @MarK I edited my response, I set up my if statement a bit differently to cover some unusual cases, take a look.  Good luck from a fellow hockey fan.

Comment: @ R.S.  When I copy/paste your df and function. It is not working... I get a lot of errors such as " unexpected '{ ' " ,"object name not found",  "object lastname not found " and " object df.sub not found". I am trying to find why... Is it working on your computer ?

Comment: @MarK I think the formatting got messed up when I pasted here.  It should be fixed now, try again.  I also added an argument check.

Comment: @Jagr and finally I also included a version insensitive to case.  Ok I think this thread has reached it's limit.  Good luck.