# Partial String Match in R using the %in% operator?

Tags: r, regex, string, string-matching, in-operator

I'm curious to know if it is possible to do partial string matches using the %in% operator in R. I know that there are many ways to use stringr, etc. to find partial string matches, but my current code works easier using the %in% operator.

For instance, imagine this vector:

```
x <- c("Withdrawn", "withdrawn", "5-Withdrawn", "2-WITHDRAWN", "withdrawnn")
```

I want each of these to be TRUE because the string contains "Withdrawn", but only the first is TRUE:

```
x %in% c("Withdrawn")
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I tried using regex to at least make it case insensitive, but that made everything false:

```
x %in% c("(?i)Withdrawn")
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

So, is it possible to yield TRUE on all of these using the %in% operator with maybe a wrapper? Because it's easy to use tolower() or toupper(), I'm not *as* concerned with the case sensitivity; however, it is important to me that the code would trigger "withdrawn", "withdrawnn", and "5-withdrawn".

EDIT: This question was marked as a duplicate of this question [Case-insensitive search of a list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671719/case-insensitive-search-of-a-list-in-r); however, it is different because it is asking if partial string matches are possible using the %in% operator. The linked question does not use the %in% operator at all.

Comment: Use `grep`/`grepl` with the regex, see [Case-insensitive search of a list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671719/case-insensitive-search-of-a-list-in-r)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I know that there are other ways to match strings, but this question is trying to see how it could be done using the %in% operator. The link that you sent does not discuss using the %in% operator.

Comment: But https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40174604/r-in-operator-control-case-sensitivity?noredirect=1&lq=1 is closed with that exact question. So, it is a valid dupe.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, that one only asks for case sensitivity. Mine is asking primarily for partial string match using the %in% operator. In my request, I even mentioned that the case sensitivity was a minor request, and I can remove it if that will help make it not seem like a duplicate.

Comment: Added [partial string matching - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901500/partial-string-matching-r) to the dupe links. Still, use grep/grepl.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I disagree. It’s sufficiently different that it doesn’t obviously apply without explanatory comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%in%` does not support this: It’s a wrapper for the `match` function, which uses equality comparison to establish matches, not regular expression matching. However, you can implement your own:

```
`%rin%` = function (pattern, list) {
     vapply(pattern, function (p) any(grepl(p, list)), logical(1L), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
}
```

And this can be used like `%in%`:

```
〉'^foo.*' %rin% c('foo', 'foobar')
[1] TRUE
```

Note that the result differs from your requirement to work as you’d expect from `grepl`: pattern matching is *asymmetric*, you can’t swap the left and right-hand side. If you just want to match a list against a single regular expression, use `grepl` directly:

```
〉grepl("(?i)Withdrawn", x)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Or, if you prefer using an operator:

```
`%matches%` = grepl
```

```
〉"(?i)Withdrawn" %matches% x
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This explanation of how %in% works, how it can't be swapped left and right, and when to use it instead of grepl is exactly what I needed. Thank you again!